# What is the fastest algorithm to solve the eigenvector of a transition matrix of a Markov Chain?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a transition matrix of a Markov chain, $P$, I want to solve the left eigenvector of $P$, namely a row vector $\alpha$ such that
$$
\alpha P = \alpha
$$

I know the algorithm to solve a linear equation takes $O(n^3)$, using LU decomposition.

I wonder if there is any faster algorithm?

By the way, I may not need the exact solution, approximate one is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a transition matrix, the stationary vector $\alpha$ can be found by merely computing successive powers of $P$ against a random starting vector; this is the [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration). In practice, for a large $P$, the matrix is sparse and it is easy to calculate the map $x \mapsto Px$, so you can use the [Arnoldi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi%27s_algorithm).

In general, you can *never* get an exact solution to the eigenvalue problem, in that you'll never be able to find a closed form algebraic expression; this is because solving for eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix is equivalent to finding the roots of its $n$th degree characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Of course, for this question, the eigenvalue is known, exactly, to be $1$.

Comment: I thought about successive powers, thank you very much, I will have a try.

Comment: Gerry is right however. Since the eigenvalue is known, there are some other methods. Power method is advantageous because you obtain the eigenvector without even knowing the eigenvalue, but in this case that advantage isn't so great. You could, for example, calculate the SVD or QR decomposition of $I - P$ in order to find the null space.